# Heisenbug alert: Featured tab is sometimes borked

Tags: bug, bounties, meta, bountied-tab

I just noticed this on the mSO featured page:

[image]

The page which the tab links to, however, shows that there's a good dozen or so bountied questions. This seems to only happen on the featured tab itself.

Could we fix this?

**Edit**: I'm seeing this seemingly randomly on the home page as well.

It's also just been reported on [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/240/the-active-question-page-shows-0-ongoing-bounties-when-in-fact-there-is-one).

Edit again: I just saw it on Stack Overflow, but while *not* on the featured tab:

[image]

[image]

So this bizarre (cache?) bug is still alive.

Comment: Odd, it shows 18 correctly for me

Comment: @RichardTingle See update, it seems to be only on the featured tab itself, although I've seen it other places.

Comment: This was happening on Stack Overflow as well, and not just on the featured tab.

Comment: Looks like a temporary glitch, network wide. All is normal again now.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Still borked for me.

Comment: @Undo Ah yes, from the questions tab it is correct, from the homepage it is 0

Comment: @Undo: probably one machine in the cluster then.

Comment: Funnily enough, new questions are still coming in through the websocket.

Comment: I am seeing *0 featured* too, only on the home page though.

Comment: @AsheeshR: there is a cluster of machines serving us; some are working, some are borked.

Comment: Observed on ie11/win7 x64 as well...

Comment: I had this happen to me on TeX.SX as well: http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4185/uh-0-featured-questions

Comment: Might have something to do with [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/216692/237685).