# Blank Screen on SE 2.0 Sites

Tags: bug, status-completed

The entire http://chess.stackexchange.com site is blank right now.

The header and footer are shown, but no questions.

[image]

Comment: Can't repro here.

Comment: Try pressing Ctrl+F5. That worked for me.

Comment: I'm getting the same issue on other beta sites too, tried hard refresh and incognito...

Comment: It's fixed now, but that was an odd 10 minute experience

Comment: I poked at this while I saw something like it on P.SE (front page renders, question tab shows no questions and 0 answers in the upper right).  The question *data* was there in the html, it just wasn't getting rendered.  I blamed caching.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The tag engine was being built when you saw this, it was a temporary error.  While not great, it's not a lingering issue - closing this out.

Comment: Hi Nick, do you know this is still happening to various sites?

Comment: @JackDouglas it happens saturday morning EST without fail *every week*, yet nothing stands out...have some ideas to look into Monday though.

Comment: Hey look! It's Saturday!