# Why are bugs invading Stack Exchange?

Tags: support, bug-reports, stackstatus

In the past hour, we've had <s>9</s> 10 meta posts reporting various bugs. Pages are showing no questions, questions are getting flipped/mixed up, etc. Clearly, this is not a coincidence. Stack Exchange is going crazy!

I see nothing posted on [StackStatus](https://www.stackstatus.net/), so I want to know: what is causing this? Is it caching? Localization? Just some turbulence in the servers? Or has the spammer threatening to hack us actually succeeded? :P

(To devs: please post the cause of this on StackStatus if you find it.)

Comment: That's because Meta was affected by the same bug, noone saw the new posts.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I'm just asking *why* it's happening. (I can't even browse meta to check anymore because apparently it has 0 questions now!)

Comment: @DoorknobofSnow it's a bad duplicate, but when you have all of this crazyness, we don't need 3 or 4 questions asking about the same thing even if the questions don't seem related.

Comment: What point is there in adding a *tenth* post about the same problem? This has happened before, the Redis memory caches have fallen over or something, it'll all work out soon enough.

Comment: Maybe it's a sign of impending big changes? Like the split of Meta?

Comment: @Pëkka probably wishful thinking.... if there was something happening you'd think they would have told us.

Comment: @psubsee2003 They did: [Stack Overflow is getting a place of its own](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/212631/162704)

Comment: Can somebody tell me why is the site normal to me? I don't see any bugs. Please help me.

Comment: @Yannis I meant "the migration is happening this weekend, be prepared for some bumps along the way".

Comment: @psubsee2003 That... would ruin the surprise, wouldn't it?

Comment: @user689 This is probably caching related, and already resolved. Don't worry about it.

Comment: Please see [this answer and comment by Nick Craver](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/216676/blank-screen-on-se-2-0-sites/216692#comment704778_216692).